# What is the best way to modify text on Microsoft Word Document

Tags: ms-word, extract

What is the best way to modify text on Microsoft Word Document ?

Which libray can i use under Linux for doing that ?

Comment: It's not possible to really answer what is best because it is not clear from your question what you are trying to achieve. A first thing to have a look at under Linux would be OpenOffice/LibreOffice though (but it really depends on what you want to do).

Comment: What is your preferred programming language?  For example, if it was Java, you could use docx4j or POI.